# Create IIS 6 application pool

Tags: command-line, iis-6

Can someone let me know how (or point me to right direction) I can create an application pool and set an application to use the newly created pool using commandline? Application has already been added to IIS but need to create a new pool and use it for this new application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I gathered, in case anyone else is looking for the same thing:

```
rem // Creates a new application pool called MyAppPool
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\ADSUTIL.VBS CREATE w3svc/AppPools/MyAppPool IIsApplicationPool

rem // if running under different user name and password
rem CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\ADSUTIL.VBS SET w3svc/AppPools/MyAppPool/WamUserName "domain\username"
rem CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\ADSUTIL.VBS SET w3svc/AppPools/MyAppPool/WamUserPass "pass"
rem CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\ADSUTIL.VBS SET w3svc/AppPools/MyAppPool/AppPoolIdentityType 3
========================================

rem // create a new virtual directory (creates vdir "Test" and set it to D:\WebSites\MyWebSite
CSCRIPT %SystemRoot%\system32\iisvdir.vbs /Create W3SVC/1/ROOT Test D:\WebSites\MyWebSite
=================================

rem // assign MyAppPool to "Test" web site
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\ADSUTIL.VBS SET W3SVC/1/ROOT/Test/AppPoolId MyAppPool
```